# How can I prevent the SD version of a TV show from downloading in iTunes when I purchase an HD show?

Tags: itunes, video

When I buy a TV show in iTunes in high-definition, at the time iTunes starts to download the show, it actually begins downloading **two** versions of the show: one in standard definition, and one in high definition.

**This is a *waste* of my bandwidth!**

I only care to have the HD version of a TV show downloaded.  I've tried to cancel the SD version download that's paired with the HD one I ordered, and that temporarily solves the problem, but the *next* time I use iTunes to download something else, it seems to remember and restarts previously cancelled SD downloads!  Must I completely download the SD version, and then delete it in order to clear the queue?  That doesn't save my bandwidth :-(

Is there any way to prevent iTunes from downloading the SD version of a TV show I buy in HD?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to prevent this permanently, automatically.

For each individual purpose, you can contact iTunes Music Store customer support, and as them to remove the SD version from your downloads queue, but bear in mind that you will not be able to transfer the movie to any iPods etc that only support SD (most of them, except for the very latest incarnations).

Source: [Second result of a google search](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9250576)